# Symfony: I Can't store primary key values

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem, I have a table (downloads) with two fields: Token (primary key) and value.

I have my entity Downloads with these methods (only show token methods, value works right):

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $token;

/**
 * Set token
 *
 * @param string $token
 * @return Downloads
 */

public function setToken($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get token
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getToken()
{
    return $this->token;
}
```

But, when I do this in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$Download = new Downloads();
        $Download->setToken($token);       
        $Download->setValid($now); 
$em->persist($Download); 
$em->flush();
```

Object is well created, but in my database Valid is stored correctly, and token is store empty!!

if I see the values, util $em->flush(); object download has two correct values, but after this, token (primary key) disappear his value.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the @ORM\GeneratedValue
(strategy="IDENTITY") because it is the one that causes doctrine to generate value for Token.
hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create  auto increment for your columns like this

```
 /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I have other tables all without auto increment fields and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid answer, but have you tried:

- Clearing your Symfony cache
- Restarting Apache

It might have to do with Doctrine caching.

Comment: Yes, thanks but this isn't the problem. I don't know if is anything in the creation of the table...